# Embedded vimeo video blank when returning to web page on iPhone 6s

Tags: ios, iframe, safari, vimeo, iphone-6

With mobile safari on iPhone 6s:

View web page with embedded vimeo video in an iframe.
https://iframe-test-ios.netlify.com/

Then some combination involving:

View another tab.

Open another ios app.

Wait for 5 mins.

Go back and resume viewing page in mobile safari
->Video is blank

I have read about bfcache and tried using the window.onpageshow event to restart things but it doesn't seem to fire. I dont need this in other browsers.

```
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe id="iframe1" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/332447363 
background=1&autopause=1&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" 
webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen loop autopause>
</iframe> 
</body>
```

When returning to the page in Safari I would expect the video to resume playing in a loop or at least show anything. Other devices and browsers resume looping playback.